# Why won't the simple javascript search() function not work on ajax delivered output?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The output I am getting is this html:

```
<form action="?next=/pm/write/" method="post">

    <label>Recipient:</label>
    <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
    <input type="text" name="recipients" id="id_recipients" />

    <br />

    <label>Subject:</label>
    <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="120" />

    <br />

    <label>Body:</label>

    <textarea id="id_body" rows="12" cols="55" name="body"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="yes" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="no" />
</form>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$('#ajaxForm input[type="submit"]').live('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pm/write/',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#ajaxForm form').serialize(),
        success: function(output) {

            if (output.search('errorlist') != -1) {
                alert('error found');
            }
            else {
                alert('all good');
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As you can see the output does contain the string "errorlist" and the error I get is "error found". That's good but the problem is I always get this alert even when the output does not contain that "errorlist" string, how to fix this?

### UPDATE

Here's what the output looks like when there are no errors:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label>Recipient:</label>

    <input type="text" name="recipients" id="id_recipients" />

    <br />

    <label>Subject:</label>


    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="120" />

    <br />

    <label>Body:</label>

    <textarea id="id_body" rows="12" cols="55" name="body"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="yes" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="no" />

</form>
```

Comment: I wonder what's so simple about this `search` function. Is it something you invented recently and wrote a browser which would support it natively?

Comment: I think you will have to show us what the output looks like when there are no errors.  That's the case you're asking us to help with right?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov It's [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) ;-) Assuming, of course, that `output` is a String (or string) value.

Comment: @Darin why would I need to invent it? - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp. @jfriend00 updated.

Comment: @Sammy One or more of the things stated in the post *cannot* be true. Check the version used is the version in the post and there is nothing silly going on -- consider a jsfiddle to "prove it". `String.search` will only return -1 if the *regex* (implicitly converted) passed to it was not found. In this case, `indexOf` should be equivalent (as there are no special regex constructs being used).

Comment: There has to be something else going on.  This jsFiddle on the exact text you posted shows that the logic works if the data is what you say it is: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mvpnh/.  I'd suggest you break on the response and examine it manually to see what is in there that is causing the match or what logic flaw there is in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be far better off returning more structured data than just a chunk of HTML. Consider returning a JSON structure that looks like:

```
{
   error: false,
   errormsg: 'blah blah blah',
   html: '<html>.....</html>'
}
```

instead. Then it'd be a simple matter of

```
if (output.error) {
   alert(errormsg);
} else {
   ...
}
```

---

Ok, if changing the serverside isn't an option, try this:

```
if (output.search(/errorlist/) == -1) {
   alert ("error found");
} else {
   alert ("all good");
}
```

The search call expects a regex, not just a plain string.

Comment: I would have gone this route but I am working with server side code in a language I don't understand (Python) and have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dataType-parameter (or add if you don't use jQuery.ajaxSetup())

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pm/write/',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#ajaxForm form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'html', //or  dataType: 'text'
    success: function(output) {

        if (output.search('errorlist') != -1) {
            alert('error found');
        }
        else {
            alert('all good');
        }
    }
});
```